# Custom UITableViewCell detecting multiple touches in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have implemented a custom UITableViewCell with a pan gesture on one subview.

When I try to pan two different views in different cells, both are getting affected with respective gestures. But I don't want that to happen simultaneously. I want any one cell to be affected.

Can someone help me?

Updated Code

I have added pan gesture in Custom tableview cell itself and also handling its pan gesture in  custom cell itself

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
[self addPanGesture:_shadowView];
}


-(void)addPanGesture:(UIView *)view
{
      panRecongiser = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGestureHere:)];
      [panRecongiser setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
      [panRecongiser setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
      panRecongiser.delegate = self;
      [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
      [view addGestureRecognizer:panRecongiser];
}

  -(void)handlePanGestureHere:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     CGPoint translatedPoint = [sender translationInView:self.contentView];

     translatedPoint = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x+translatedPoint.x, self.originalCenter.y);

     if ((translatedPoint.x<(self.originalCenter.x + (self.frame.size.width/3)) && translatedPoint.x > (self.originalCenter.x - (self.frame.size.width/3)))) {
          [self updateViews:translatedPoint.x];
          [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
      }
}
```

Comment: show some code what you have tried?

Comment: Agreed, we need code.

Comment: which part of the code ..?(how pan gesture is implemented ..?)

Comment: yes, how you have implemented pan gesture for cells? Show code of that.

Comment: How did you add the `pan` gesture to your custom TableView Cell? Show that code and let us know where the code comes from (i.e. is it in your custom cell).

Comment: Updated the code in custom tableview cell ..

Answer (score 0):

```
Please set the tag.
Using this tag you can easily distinguish every PanGesture.
```

Hope it will helps you.Thanks